# Stuck at Busybox

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, initramfs, busybox

I have a big problem and I can't fix it
So i was installing windows and removed the partition from there and got an error that i can't use this hard drive so i restarted my computer and got this error and now i don't know what to do, i just wanted to clean my disk and use it on windows

and i don't have access to bios or boot menu i don't know why

The command line here:

```
[  1.184301] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bios: 00B 1 d7500086 d7500086 
/dev/sda1: The filesystem size (according to the superblock) is 244190208 blocks 
The physical size of the device is 244189952 blocks 
Either the superblock or the partition table is likely to be corrupt! 

/dev/sda1: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY. 
        (i.e., without -a or -p options) 
fsck exited with status code 4 
The root filesystem on /dev/sda1 requires a manual fsck 

BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-19ubuntu2) built-in shell (ash) 
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands. 

(initramfs)
```

Comment: Which partition did you remove? Windows or Ubuntu? Please see my quick answer, and if it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking the checkmark and up-arrow icons just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: I neved had even windows partition on the disk so i deleted ubuntu partition

Comment: Then your disk is effectively empty? Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and either show me `sudo fdisk -l` or a screenshot of `gparted`.

Answer (score 0):

At the (initramfs) prompt, type `fsck -f /dev/sda1`, then `reboot`.

For 18.04 or newer... (or if the above steps don't work for you)...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Update #1:**

If Windows is the only OS that you want, then boot the Ubuntu Live USB, start `gparted`, and lay down a fresh partition table (this will wipe the drive). Use MBR if you have an older BIOS computer, or GPT if you have a newer UEFI computer or a large disk. Then go ahead and install Windows.

Comment: last I checked, initramfs doesn't have fsck support.  It has builtins.  They should *probably* boot to a Live environment to do the fsck as well.

Comment: @ThomasWard yes, `fsck` will work at the (initramfs) prompt, as will `reboot`... but yes... booting to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB will always work.

Comment: @ThomasWard at the (initramfs) prompt, you can also type `exit`.

Comment: But i have problem i dont have access to the boot menu in this menu https://imgur.com/a/iNlrHRS i dont can move even the buttons like up or down and when the computer logo comes yea i see the bios f12 and boot menu del and when i click del nothing happens and goes automatic to the grub

Comment: @Linksu lets be clear. Are you getting to a (initramfs) prompt as your screenshot shows, or a `Grub rescue` prompt? Do you have a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB?

Comment: Directly going to (initramfs) and yes i have ubuntu live usb

Comment: @Linksu and your intention is to install Windows or Ubuntu?

Comment: Windows for my school project but i dont can install the windows if i still get the same error on windows setup :/

Comment: @heynnema I just want full clear disk to install windows but i dont cant because the ubuntu is still on the disk but i dont have anymore access to the normal ubuntu

Comment: If Windows is the only OS that you want, then boot the Ubuntu Live USB, start `gparted`, and lay down a fresh partition table (this will wipe the drive). Use MBR if you have an older BIOS computer, or GPT if you have a newer UEFI computer or a large disk. Then go ahead and install Windows.

Comment: @heynnema Update now i am on grub rescue mode so i connected the hard disk to my windows 10 computer and now i can see it and i formated the disk and now it its but yea still problem i will tell it later i need to go now for while so i will comeback soon with this problem so one problem solved but now other